# Is it possible to use table valued parameter in JasperReports?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, jasper-reports

Is it possible use [Table Valued Parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-table-valued-parameters) in JasperReports?

I created a new type on SQL SERVER, and i'm trying pass it to jasper sql procedure as param:

```
CREATE TYPE codlist AS TABLE (
    [cod] int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
GO
```

I tried in Jasper Studio, but I have some errors, when I set table parameter as object:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Operand type clash: varbinary is incompatible with codlist.
```

When I set table parameter as SQLServerDataTable: `Parameter type not supported in query`

See my working JDBC test with a pure Java code:

```
// Create an in-memory data table.  
SQLServerDataTable sourceDataTable = new SQLServerDataTable();

// Define metadata for the data table.  
sourceDataTable.addColumnMetadata("cod", java.sql.Types.INTEGER);

// Populate the data table.  
sourceDataTable.addRow(344057);
sourceDataTable.addRow(344058);
sourceDataTable.addRow(344132);
sourceDataTable.addRow(344135);
sourceDataTable.addRow(344159);
// Pass the data table as a table-valued parameter using a prepared statement.  
SQLServerPreparedStatement pStmt
        = (SQLServerPreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(
                "EXECUTE dbo.procedure_test_table_valued_parameter ?;");
pStmt.setStructured(1, "dbo.codlist", sourceDataTable);

try (ResultSet rs = pStmt.executeQuery()) {
    while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + " - " + rs.getString(2));
    }
}
```

I will call a stored procedure that will receive as a parameter a *Table Valued Parameter*.
I tried it but it doesn't accept that I pass this object, and it does not accept any other: array, lists, etc.

This is my jrxml

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Principal" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="BlankPage" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="dc6d0467-36c2-4eb9-ab5e-78e7d903d9aa">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="SQLSRV"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.SQLQueryDesigner.sash.w1" value="265"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.SQLQueryDesigner.sash.w2" value="724"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <parameter name="PATH" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[""]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="COD" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[94807]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="CODLIST" class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataTable" isForPrompting="false">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
    </parameter>
    <queryString language="plsql">
        <![CDATA[EXEC dbo.pr_with_table_as_parameter $P{CODLIST}]]>
    </queryString>
```

Comment: Show the jrxml that you are using, definition of parameter and query. Jasper-report uses [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), not `SQLServerPreparedStatement` so I guess this will be hard to get it to work

Comment: Yes, if the jasper reports use the SQLServerPreparedStatement, it CAN WORK. But as long as it uses the PreparedStatement, I also find it difficult.
I added a snippet of the jrxml code in the post.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `plsql` by [default](https://github.com/Jaspersoft/jasperreports/blob/4d2d51e316be3a581a0f1b4df92677009c4a897f/jasperreports/src/default.jasperreports.properties#L36) this use the [PlSqlQueryExecuterFactory](https://github.com/Jaspersoft/jasperreports/blob/895d17ad3fb3bc8cdbb961edaa9a073e110a05d0/jasperreports/src/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/query/PlSqlQueryExecuterFactory.java) that extends the [JRJdbcQueryExecuterFactory](https://github.com/Jaspersoft/jasperreports/blob/895d17ad3fb3bc8cdbb961edaa9a073e110a05d0/jasperreports/src/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/query/JRJdbcQueryExecuterFactory.java) which [returns](https://github.com/Jaspersoft/jasperreports/blob/895d17ad3fb3bc8cdbb961edaa9a073e110a05d0/jasperreports/src/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/query/JRJdbcQueryExecuterFactory.java#L138) a [JRJdbcQueryExecuter](https://github.com/Jaspersoft/jasperreports/blob/895d17ad3fb3bc8cdbb961edaa9a073e110a05d0/jasperreports/src/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/query/JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java) that will use a [java.sql.PreparedStatement](https://github.com/Jaspersoft/jasperreports/blob/895d17ad3fb3bc8cdbb961edaa9a073e110a05d0/jasperreports/src/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/query/JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java#L114) and when an un handled class type is used call [`statement.setObject(parameterIndex, parameterValue)`](https://github.com/Jaspersoft/jasperreports/blob/895d17ad3fb3bc8cdbb961edaa9a073e110a05d0/jasperreports/src/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/query/JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java#L775), since in your case it's not a procedure call (query does not match [this](https://github.com/Jaspersoft/jasperreports/blob/895d17ad3fb3bc8cdbb961edaa9a073e110a05d0/jasperreports/src/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/query/JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java#L106))

## Conclusion

**No it's not possibile** as it is.

**Yes it is possibile** you need to implement your own `QueryExecuterFactory` that returns your own `JRQueryExecuter`, register it in `jasperreports.properties` with your own name, implement your call (driver) and then indicate it in your `<queryString language="mynewsql">`.

Follow the steps above that showed how the `psql` QueryExecuterFactory was setup and you should be fine.